# Img not loading with img class?

Tags: css, image

I'm trying to setup a page background that scales with resolution but still looks nice.. heres what Im using..

The site is http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress, If you inspect it with firebug, it just doesnt load the image... but if I add that path straight into the css, it works.

Additionally, I use this same code on www.gd-gaming.com for that background and it works perfectly. Help needed!!

```
<div id="background"> <img class="background" src="images/bgmain.jpg" /> </div>


#background {
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1; 


}

img.background {
width: 100%;
}

fieldset, img {
border: 0 none;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/images/bgmain.jpg really exists?

Comment: Maybe its as dumb as me using an incorrect file path, let me try quick.

Comment: Yep, its in that exact filepath and still wont load. Very interesting.

Comment: Probably permissions.... check the folder for read permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mak sure that `images/bgmain.jpg` really exists. I could not find it on your server. Instead, I replaced it with

```
<img class="background" src="/images/GDG/skyrimpapa.jpg">
```

on your /wordpress page (the dame image used on your home page) and it worked fine. Looks like either your image does not exist or you do not have permissions for that image set properly.

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming when I'm inserting an image from within the html i need to use the FULL path?

Comment: Glad it was simple in the end :)